# Getting Cron Expressions from a Quartz Job

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I was wondering if it possible to get the trigger cron expression from a Quartz Job.

I'm trying to do this for a few unit tests.

**Gist from bassmartin's Answer**

https://gist.github.com/jdgiotta/8c33402c1a026c2ccb12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible:

Inject the JobManagerService

```
 def jobManagerService
```

Fetch the triggers of a job

```
List triggers = jobManagerService.quartzScheduler.getTriggersOfJob(JobKey.jobKey(MyJob.canonicalName, GrailsJobClassConstants.DEFAULT_GROUP))
```

Assuming your triggers are CronTrigger

```
triggers.each { trigger ->
   println trigger.getCronExpression()
}
```

Comment: I should probably change the test type from unit to integration.